# Method to clip a plane to a bounding cube in Python

Tags: python, 3d, point-clouds

I have an infinite plane in 3D defined by the parameters in the equation *Ax + By + Cz = D* and I would like to clip it to a bounding cube.

The plane parameters consist of a list of *A, B, C,* and *D* and the bounding cube consists of a list of the eight corner points in 3D space. The desired output is the four corner points of the plane after being clipped.

```py
plane_params = [A, B, C, D]
bbox_points = [[x0, y0, z0], ... , [x7, y7, z7]]

plane_corners = clip_to_bounding_box(plane_params, bbox_points)
```

Can someone provide a Python method for clipping the plane to these bounds which returns the four corner points of the plane or alternatively the mathematical formula for a bounded plane?

Thanks :)

Comment: Find the intersections of the plane with each of the 12 edges of the cube. Some of the edges will intersect with the plane, some won't. The resulting list of intersection points defines a polygon, which is the "clipped plane" that you want.